# NGINX no muestra imágenes Web

Tags: nginx, proxy

Soy un novato en Nginx y tengo que montar un servidor proxy (192.168.1.100) que redireccione el tráfico desde el puerto 80 hasta el puerto 1234 de otro servidor (192.168.1.200).

Eso lo he logrado; cuando introduzco mi IP pública aparece la dirección 192.168.1.200:1234. El problema es que lo único que muestra la página es texto, sin ninguna foto.

Imágenes:
Esto es lo que muestra:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esto es lo que debería mostrar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de mi *.conf:

```
server {
   listen   80;
   listen   [::]:80;

   access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

   location {
      proxy_pass http://192.168.1.200:1234/customerSite/login.html;
      }

   error_page 404 /404.html;
   location = /40x.html{
   }
   
   error_page 500 502 503 504 /50.html;
   location = /50x.html{
   }
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Estás siempre devolviendo el mismo fichero: login.html. Por tanto, no tienes imágenes, ficheros CSS o javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Estás siempre devolviendo el mismo fichero: login.html. Por tanto, no tienes imágenes, ficheros CSS o javascript. Prueba modificando el valor de `proxy_pass`:

```
location / {
      proxy_pass http://192.168.1.200:1234/customerSite/;
}
```

De este modo si pides `/index.html`, se redigirá a `http://192.168.1.200:1234/customerSite/index.html`, pero si pides por ejemplo `/styles.css`, esto se mapeará a `http://192.168.1.200:1234/customerSite/styles.css`

Comment: He modificado el código tal y como sugieres, pero no ha funcionado. La página continúa mostrando el mismo contenido en blanco.

Comment: @Drageir intena modo incognito , y agrega los errores que te muestra en la consola

Comment: En la consola aparece el siguiente error varias veces:  "La hoja de estilos http://IP-Publica/login.html;jsessionid=D910D8E37DD56750E5A588D2EB3437F0 no se ha cargado porque su tipo MIME, 'text/html' no es 'text/css'"

Comment: Has reiniciado nginx después de los cambios? Te sigue devolviendo siempre index.html

Comment: Sí, he reiniciado nginx con systemctl restart nginx.

Comment: He revisado los logs de nginx y me aparece el siguiente error: [error] 22297#0: *13 open() “/www/data/XXXX/commons/js/materialize/js/init_cs.js” failed (2:no such file or directory), client: PUBLIC-IP, server: , request: “GET /XXXX/commons/js/materialize/js/init_cs.js HTTP/1.1”.

Comment: Parece que el fichero no está donde debería

Answer (score 0):

Yo solo lo logré cambiando el código HTML y poniendo la url en lugar de la ubicación del archivo, pero significaría cambiar todo el código, solo que los otros recursos tampoco los carga.

Comment: Hola Hugo bienvenido y gracias por colaborar, te sugiero que antes de responder, leas cuidadosamente la pregunta y los comentarios, así tendrás la posibilidad de dar una respuesta acorde, en este caso, por ejemplo, estás contestando una pregunta hecha hace dos años y medio, por otro lado, tu respuesta es muy vaga, tratamos de explicar como se soluciona el problema, ver [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor